Blazor Server - Paginating a table with TPT type records performs really bad
First, I'll give you some context. I have modeled an entity using the TPT inheritance. In short, it looks something like this:
class Notification {
   int ID PK
   int Identifier
   dateTime CreatedAt - This on is indexed
   ...
}

class SmsNotification {
   int ID
   string Message
}

It's safe to say that I can't turn back at this point and remodel the entities because it's too risky, so I need some advice which can help me in the current context. The records are produced by some worker app.
Next, we have a Blazor Server app, .Net 6, hosted in k8s, with direct access to the DB. We have a table (Radzen, don't know if it matters or not) where we need to load the SmsNotifications. We have a filter that kicks in by default and makes it so that we only fetch the Notifications from the current date but you can change the filter to retrieve older Notifications as well.
We use EF to load the data from an Azure Sql Server, DTU based, I think we have the S7 plan. The table uses offset pagination so we will have a skip and a take value. It also needs to get the count of all records so that it can display the number of pages. This style of table was a requirment, I'd like to know if we can somehow save this implementation or if the final answer is that the implementation/design choice is wrong for what we are dealing with.
Everything is async. The EF context comes for the EF factory.
The problem:
On a good day, that means low volumes of data, the number of SmsNotifications will be around 350k. Loading 10 of them in the interface is not a dealbraker. But we also have to do the totalCount query so that we can know the number of pages. From what I've seen, that count goes rampage and the Azure Sql Server hits 100% usage almost instanly. Most of the time, the query fails with a timeout and we have to reload the page several times in order to get data.
And we are only talking about the first interaction with the page, so only the filter on the CreatedAt column kicks in. If I try to use other filters it's worse.
I have also analyzed the query that EF generates. As I've said, we are loading SmsNotifications, so we need data from both tables. EF uses a LEFT JOIN and creates some sort of discriminator on its own and also uses that, don't know why really, a simple INNER JOIN between the Notifications and SMSNotifications table is enough to determine that that Notification is an SMSNotification. Maybe you can also clarify this EF behaviour for me ...
So right now I have 3 culprits in mind:

the count - I am not sure if I can do anything here, is there a way to do offset pagination without the count?;
the TPT inheritance that the entity is using;
blazor server, maybe SignalR is affecting it...;
the DTU based plan, idk, maybe the application doesn't know how to effectivly use the resources that it has, I have also thought of switching to VCores but I'm not use if it will help;
the resources assigned to the blazor server app itself, maybe its somehow bottlenecked and that also affects the query performance;

What I have tried so far:

analyze the query plan and try different indexes;
analyzing the query with azure query insights;
created a view over the SmsNotifications and Notifications tables and made EF load the data from the view, the view is basically a join between the 2 tables and I am selecting only the columns that I want to display in the table as well;
after I have the first count I cache it. I only ever redo the count if the filters change;

Doing this improved the performance, meaning that its not completly unusable anymore but it's still very slow and db still goes to 100% usage...
I have runned out of ideas, I really don't understand why the Azure Sql Server goes to 100% usage, the count query does have to go over a lot of data but still... the query is indexed and an S7 plan is not that small.
I appreciate any advice.
Thanks!

Can you define a view in your database that optimizes the joins, and define a DBSet that points at the view to get the data?

Hello @MrCakaShaunCurtis , thank you for the suggestion, I did that already, I think by doing this I did eliminate the performance drawback that EF was causing with the left join and discriminator, but the overall performance did not improve that much unfortunately.

Which query has bad performance?

So how fast is 1. A count run against the view? 2. A Skip/Take query against the view?  Re-reading your question suggests to me the problem is in your database design.  See https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/12/how-to-make-select-count-queries-crazy-fast/

@SvyatoslavDanyliv the query count is the one with the bad performance... its basically a select, only with the filters that I'm interested in, so on order by .. i am runnig it over a view so ef does not create any joins but in behind ,the view is created by joining 2 tables

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I'll try to come back with some benchmarks and also the query and the indexes that I have ... I can't do that right now as I won't have access to my work station for the following week. But to give you a rough estimate, the count query generates timeouts, ef has a 5 min timeout set, so its taking more than 5 minutes to run the query... what it needs to do is take the number of rows available for the current day, ~ 350k, the table itself has more than 100mil rows as we need to keep the data for the past 3 months in it but the rest of the rows are ahived daily.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I'll also take a look over that post, it seems really interesting and I might be able to improve the performance with those indexes

Do all your initial testing in SQL Management Studio or similar.  Establish pure database performance without EF in the way.

Without seeing the query in question, there are two tips to getting counts for pagination.

Simplification - The default code when fetching paginated data would be:


build query
get count (slow)
take page of data (fast)

The query you need for the page of data is complex. It will include filtering and sorting, joining for related data, projections, etc. All the count needs is the filtering so to improve performance consider a separate query for the count which only performs the filtering. No sorting, no joining, (beyond what the filtering requires) no projection or eager loading, etc.
The downside of this approach is that you could develop a disconnect between the two queries if they are completely separate. Typically though I can build an IQueryable where the filtering is done first and a count can be extracted, then append the sorting and projections to get a page of data.

Approximation - This is when working with very large datasets. Users generally don't care about an exact # of rows, but can request it. Here is an example I use:
     var query = EmployeeManagementRepository.GetAll(request.IncludeInactive); //Returns IQueryable<Employee>
     query = applySearchCriteria(query, request.SearchText);

     int cutoff = PaginatedList.CalculateItemCutoff(request.PageNumber, request.PageSize);

     var recordCount = await query.Take(cutoff).CountAsync();

     var employees = await query
         .OrderBy(x => x.LastName)
         .ThenBy(x => x.FirstName)
         .AsNoTracking()
         .ProjectTo<EmployeeSummaryViewModel>(config)
         .Skip((request.PageNumber - 1) * request.PageSize)
         .Take(request.PageSize)
     .ToListAsync();

     var paginatedList = new PaginatedList<EmployeeSummaryViewModel>(employees, request.PageNumber, request.PageSize, recordCount);



This example uses option #1 where I grab the count before ordering and projecting. However, I calculate a cut-off for the total # of rows I will count across.
The PaginatedList & CalculateItemCutoff:
/// <summary>
/// A base view model for supporting paginated data on a view.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// The pagination functionality will load up to 10 pages at a time.
/// For instance if the page size is 25, queries using this pagination
/// should load (PageSet+1) x PageSize x 10 + 1 row. This performs 
/// a staggered search where the query is always limited to 
/// loading initially no more than 10 pages of data, then if there are 
/// more records, loading 20 pages of data, then 30 only if the user
/// continues selecting the "..." 11th page option.
/// </remarks>
public abstract class PaginatedList
{
    public const int PageCount = 10;
    public const int DefaultPageSize = 25;

    public static int CalculateItemCutoff(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        return (((pageNumber - 1) / PageCount) + 1) * pageSize * PageCount + 1;
    }
}

public class PaginatedList<TViewModel> : PaginatedList where TViewModel : class
{
    public ICollection<TViewModel> CurrentPageItems { get; set; } = new List<TViewModel>();
    public int CurrentPageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
    public int PageSize { get; private set; } = DefaultPageSize;
    public int ItemCount { get; private set; }

    private readonly List<int> _pages = new();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<int> Pages
    {
        get => _pages;
    }

    public static int CalculateItemCutoff(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        return (((pageNumber - 1) / PageCount) + 1) * pageSize * PageCount + 1;
    }

    public int PageSet
    {
        get => (CurrentPageNumber - 1) / PageCount;
    }

    public bool HasMoreItems
    {
        get => Pages.Count > PageCount;
    }

    public PaginatedList(ICollection<TViewModel> currentPageItems, int currentPageNumber, int pageSize, int itemCount)
    {
        CurrentPageItems = currentPageItems;
        CurrentPageNumber = currentPageNumber;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        ItemCount = itemCount;

        computePages();
    }

    private void computePages()
    {
        var pageStart = PageSet * PageCount;
        // If we have more records than total pages # of records then add one. (Which will be rendered as "..."
        var pageEnd = ItemCount / PageSize + ((ItemCount - pageStart) % PageSize > 0 ? 1 : 0);
        _pages.Clear();
        for (int pageNumber = pageStart; pageNumber < pageEnd; pageNumber++)
            _pages.Add(pageNumber + 1);
    }
}

When the UI renders the pagination there is a key property "HasMoreItems" which it uses to determine how to render the page count. For instance with a default # of pages of 10 and page size of 25, the pagination will initially load a max of 251 items. If there are less than 250 items the page count and row count will be correct. If there are more than 250 items then the row count comes back as 251, total pages is 11 and page count is 10. This renders as pages 1-10 with a "..." page button to advance to page 11. When this "HasMoreItems" flag is set in this scenario I render the record count as a hyperlink /w "250+". Clicking on the hyperlink makes an async call to the server to get an actual row count and replaces the "250+" with the actual figure. When the user selects the "..." page button to load page 11, the pagination query caps out at 501 records, displaying "500+" for the row count with pages 11-20 & "..." assuming more than 500 total records.
The caveat of this approach is that you cannot provide/enable a "go to last page" type button in the pagination control. It will of course get slower as users go higher in the page count, but as the saying goes "The best place to hide a dead body is on page 2 of Google search results". 99.x% of the time users are looking for data on the first couple of pages. If they get too much back they will narrow down their search before flipping through pageset after pageset to find what they are looking for. If they do want an accurate count of the # of items then you can provide that capability with a single, more expensive call rather than incurring that cost for every search. It also will require rendering your own pagination control vs. 3rd party ones or integrated pagination in data grids. This wasn't so much of a barrier since it was easier to get the behaviour and styling I wanted anyways. The "Pages" collection gives the page numbers for the current page set.
Edit: Having looked at that code and usage again, I made a slight clean-up to introduce the non-generic base PaginatedList class for the static CalculateItemCutoff method.

This approach seems really interesting. I am already doing the #1 Simplication part. And I think the cutoff approach might be acceptable for the users as well, truth to be told, if they want to get to the entries from the last page, they have a few columns that they can sort by and achieve that .... I will try to implement this but I can already tell that it will surely improve the performance and I can also find a sweet spot for the cutoff that will perform well while serving the most amount of pages at a time.

Thank you for the suggestion! I can't implement it in the following week, but as soon as I get the chance I'll do this and come back with an answer.

Yep, with this you can offer the user a control with page size, so 10 items, 25, 50, 100, whatever and the cutoff calculation takes that into account. You could also customize the pages count, I just use a constant of 10 pages of results. The other factor with searching is discouraging expensive searches so ones that are most common/valuable to users are promoted by default but giving them an option for more detailed (expensive) ones. For instance string searches default to == or at worse StartsWith, not Contains. Support them entering "%term%" / "*term*" if they really need it.
